# OpenGL program keeps crashing around glDrawArrays()

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to make a function that displays a `GLuint` texture. This is what I made so far. It should output a white quad, but it just crashes:

```
position2 Q_pos[4]={{0,0},
                    {1,0},
                    {1,1},
                    {0,1}};
void blit_texture(GLuint texture,Point mid_pt,Point Scale=Point(1,1,1),
    Point rotate_angle=Point(0,0),Point focus_point=Point(0,0))
{
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glPushMatrix();
    GLtranslate2v(mid_pt);
    GLrotate3f(rotate_angle);
    GLtranslate2v(focus_point);
    glScalef(Scale.x,Scale.y,1);
        glColor4f(1,1,1,1);
        glVertexPointer( 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, Q_pos );
        glDrawArrays( GL_QUADS, 0, 4 );

    glPopMatrix();
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

I've also made some definitions for points, easier rotating etc...:

```
#define GLrotate3f(pt) glRotatef(pt.x,1,0,0),glRotatef(pt.y,0,1,0),glRotatef(pt.z,0,0,1)
#define GLtranslate2v(pt) glTranslatef(pt.x,pt.y,0);
#define GLscale2v(pt) glScalef(pt.x,pt.y,0);
class position3
{
    public:
    float x,y,z;
    position3(float X=0,float Y=0,float Z=0){
    x=X,y=Y,z=Z;}
    void operator=(float num){x=num,y=num,z=num;}
    void operator=(position3 pt){
                             x=pt.x,y=pt.y,z=pt.z;
                                }
    bool operator>(float Min)
    {
        if (x<Min || y<Min || z<Min) return 0;
        return 1;
    }
    bool operator<(float Max)
    {
        if (x>Max || y>Max || z>Max) return 0;
        return 1;
    }
};
class position2
{
    public:
    float x,y;
    position2(float X=0,float Y=0)
    {
    x=X,y=Y;
    }
    void operator=(float num){x=num,y=num;}
    void operator=(position2 pt){
                             x=pt.x,y=pt.y;
                                }
    bool operator>(float Min)
    {
        if (x<Min || y<Min) return 0;
        return 1;
    }
    bool operator<(float Max)
    {
        if (x>Max || y>Max) return 0;
        return 1;
    }
};
class color3f
{
    public:
    float r,g,b;
    color3f(float R=0,float G=0,float B=0){
    r=R,g=G,b=B;}
    void operator=(color3f cl)
    {
    r=cl.r,g=cl.g,b=cl.b;
    }
};
class Point : public position3 , public color3f
{
public:
Point(float X=0,float Y=0,float Z=0,float R=0,float G=0,float B=0)
{
    x=X,y=Y,z=Z;
    r=R,g=G,b=B;
}
};
```

If I make it in intermediate mode it works fine, even the texture appears, but when I try to use VAs it can't make a single white quad.

I did a little debugging on it and figured out that if I put `exit(42);` before the `glDrawArrays()` call it returns with 42 but if I take it after the `glDrawArrays()` the program crashes, so it seems that the problem is caused by `glDrawArrays()`.

Here is my initialization:

```
const int width=640, height=480;
glViewport(0,0,width, height );
glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, ((GLfloat)-1), (GLfloat)1);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Also, is there a method to check if VBOs are supported or not? This because I made a program with them and it worked fine on my pc (with OpenGL 4.2), but when I tried to run it on my friend's computer (with OpenGL 2.1) it crashed.

Comment: What is a "`GLuint` texture"?

Comment: "*I did a little debugging on it...*" Are you saying that you don't have a *debugger*? You might want to look into that.

Comment: I work with Code::Blocks under windows 7

Comment: It has a debugger in it. You can set break-points and everything. You don't need to use "exit(21)" or printf debugging.

Comment: I didn't found the solution but
i moved on glsl and now using other methods.
Anyways thanks for your help!